# How to add a hyperlink to the body of a feeditem with apex code

Tags: apex, feeditem

I want to add a hyperlink to the body of a feeditem with apex code. I tried to with class of EncodingUtil.urlEncode but it is not work. So I`d like to know how shall I do. Thx!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, Leisure. Can you share what code you tried and what the result was?

Comment: Yes, follows are:
String sUrlRewrite = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
newItem = new FeedItem();
newItem.ParentId = targetAccountId;
newItem.Type = 'LinkPost';
newItem.Body = 'Case subject: ' + c.Subject 
    + '\n Account Name: ' + map_accountId_account.get(c.AccountId).Name;
newItem.Title = c.Subject;
newItem.LinkUrl = sUrlRewrite + '/' + c.Id;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
      //Adding a Link post
               FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
               post.ParentId = oId; //eg. Opportunity id, custom object id..
               post.Body = 'Enter post text here';
               post.LinkUrl = 'http://www.someurl.com';
               insert post;
```

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm

You can refer a field named "type" in Feeditem that decides the body.You have following choices

**The type of FeedItem you can use is 
    LinkPost—a URL posting on a feed**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My mate also had told me about this parameter, it is ok. Your are right!

Comment: If the answer answers your question its helpful if you mark it ticked and also upvote .Marking it as answer helps others while surfing